# How to get git to stop tracking a deleted file?

Tags: git

When I type in `git status` I get the following:

> On branch master Changes to be committed:   (use "git restore --staged
> ..." to unstage)
> new file:   MyDeletedFile.hpp
>
> Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add/rm ..." to update
> what will be committed)   (use "git restore ..." to discard
> changes in working directory)
> deleted:    MyDeletedFile.hpp

'MyDeletedFile.hpp' has been deleted. How do I get git to stop showing this in git status?  I'm not sure how to add these changes to a commit since the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can record to the index the deletion of that file (`git add -- MyDeletedFile.hpp`), and all you need to do is a `git commit`.

Once the commit is done, Git will no longer show that file in the status.

The [OP Rahul Iyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266109/rahul-iyer) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70562698/how-to-get-git-to-stop-tracking-a-deleted-file#comment124735528_70562705) having to do two commits, the second one handling the deleted file. That could happen when the deleted file has not the same case (`mydeletedfile.hpp` vs. `MyDeletedFile.hpp`)

Comment: @RahulIyer Yes, a commit is best done after adding the changes you want to commit.